# Kill a process on file save

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to tell neovim to kill sxhkd and run sxhkd after I close its config file (sxhkdrc). This is what I have in my `init.vim`

```
autocmd BufWritePost *sxhkdrc pkill sxhkd; setsid sxhkd
```

I get the following error

```
"sxhkdrc" 9L, 136C written
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*sxhkdrc":
E492: Not an editor command: pkill sxhkd; setsid sxhkd
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I can run `pkill sxhkd; setsid sxhkd` in the terminal without error, but for some reason my init.vim file does not know how to execute this command.

What can I do to kill a processes, such as sxhkd, when I save its config file?

Comment: [vi.se] exists too :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing an external command from inside Vim, we use the `!` prefix to run the command in a non-interactive shell. You can test this by executing `:!ls` for a quick demonstration.

In your case, Vim is informing you that it doesn't understand the command you're giving it. Which is fair enough: it's not an editor command, it's a command designed to be executed from the terminal. You probably want:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *sxhkdrc !pkill sxhkd; setsid sxhkd
```

Edit: Alex points out in comments that sxhkd is a daemon, so backgrounding it with `&` would make more sense:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *sxhkdrc !pkill sxhkd && setsid sxhkd &
```

Comment: does this mean that I should also change`setsid` to `!setsid`?

Comment: Nope! You can also demonstrate this by `:!ls; echo done`. As you can see, both commands get executed in the non-interactive shell.

Comment: For posterity, it is also with noting that the `&` was needed for the command to not hang. The resulted in the following `autocmd BufWritePost *sxhkdrc !pkill sxhkd; setsid sxhkd &`

Comment: Might be worth using `system()` instead

Comment: @Alex `&` will background the process (I'm not familiar with sxhkdrc, apparently it's a daemon?) For commands that do work and then exit, you can also use `&&` which will only execute the second command if the first exits without error.